# changing openlayers clutter radius

Tags: cluster-analysis, jsp-tags, openlayers

I used openlayers clustter strategy to cluster a dataset from a geoserver.

I used the following code in styling of clusters.

```
var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style( {
                    pointRadius :20,
                    fillColor :'#FFFF00',
                    fillOpacity :0.5,
                    strokeColor :'#FFFFFF',
                    strokeWidth :2,
                    strokeOpacity :0.5
                });
var myStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap( {
    "default" :myStyle
});
```

This works nicely if I write the code in html pages and also in jsp pages.

when I want to change the cluster radius dynamically according to the data point count in each cluster I just had to do the following change to the above code.

```
var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style( {
                    pointRadius :"${radius}",
                    fillColor :'#FFFF00',
                    fillOpacity :0.5,
                    strokeColor :'#FFFFFF',
                    strokeWidth :2,
                    strokeOpacity :0.5
                }, {
                    context : {
                        radius: function(feature) {
                            return Math.min(feature.attributes.count, 7) +3;;

                        }
                    }
                });
var myStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap( {
    "default" :myStyle
});
```

This also woks fine, if I write the code in an html page.

But, when I wanna use the above second code in jsp pages, it gives me the mozilla firebug error => Unexpected value parsing r attributes.

can someone help me?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure your jsp is outputting the same html and js? Use firebug to see what line is broken.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes, identical code but the only difference is the extension " .jsp ". I think this problem occurs because of the ${radius} variable.

Answer (score 0):

From JSP2 spec you should be able to escape the EL
With something like :
`${'${'}radius}` in your JSP page

Good luck.